# Pine Script - Problem when multipliying inside "show_last"

Tags: pine-script, trading

I am trying to make a Replay Mode in Tradingview with pine script.
but kinda have some trouble with different time frames and to sync them together.

i am trying to hide the candles with plotcandle function with show_last, but when switching timeframe, i need to automatically change the show_last digit also. So tried to divide the user input with the current timeframe.

Eg,
if 1min, then I divide the user input by 1
if 15min, then I divide the user input by 15

then i will get the exact number of candles that should be hidden in all timeframes

but i am getting an error when i try to use the multiplied number inside "show_last"

please help as soon as possible

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © FAHEEMSAM

//@version=4
study("Replay Pro")

body = if close > open
    color.green
else if close < open
    color.red
else if close == open
    color.black

timeframe = if timeframe.period == "1"
    1
else if timeframe.period == "3"
    3
else if timeframe.period == "5"
    5
else if timeframe.period == "15"
    15
else if timeframe.period == "30"
    30
    


display = input(title="Display", type=input.integer, defval=1, minval=1) * timeframe

plotcandle(open, high, low, close, color= body, wickcolor = color.black, bordercolor = color.black)

plotcandle(open, high, low, close, color= color.white, wickcolor = color.white, bordercolor = color.white, show_last=display)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the refman entry for [`plotcandle()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_plotcandle) mentions, the argument to `show_last` must be of "input integer" type, which means it can use an input value, but not one that is then used in a calculation such as you are doing, because it then becomes a "simple integer", which is not allowed for that particular parameter.

One workaround, if you can calculate which bars to start printing on, would be to use conditional values for your ``plotcandle()` calls:

```
cond = ...
plotcandle(cond ? open : na, cond ? high : na, ...)
```